# Using Pandas, how to delete an empty column in a dataframe with a 2-level multindex headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Excel spreadsheet with a 2-level multiindex of column headers:

[image]

I am loading the Excel file into a Pandas dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.read_excel('Bike Total Data.xlsx', header=[0,1], sheet_name="Control (E)")
```

And I would like to delete the blank (black) columns using Pandas (as there are hundreds).

The reason I need to do this is actually because of another issue I'm facing ([In Pandas, a duplicate column is appearing with ".1" appended to name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65127984/in-pandas-a-duplicate-column-is-appearing-with-1-appended-to-name)). But I have not found a solution for that problem, which is why I'm trying to remove the blank columns… and would hopefully thereafter be able to either add the black columns back in, or add a thick border to the right side of each **`MV (calc)`** after all the necessary data manipulations are done. But I digress.

How can I delete the blank columns in this dataframe using Pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case the black columns are the only ones in `df` consisting entirely of `NaN`s, you could try removing them by using either

```py
clean_df = df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
```

or

```py
clean_df = df.loc[:, df.notna().any()]
```

Comment: They aren't the only ones with the NaNs, as can be seen in the example shown.

Comment: But are there any other columns containing only NaNs? In the example, D and G are the only ones.